# How do I put multiple data frames having different dimensions into a single list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

For example, I have three dataframes: df1,df2, and df3 like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(11:15))  
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1:9), y = c(11:19), z = c(8:16) )    
df3 <- data.frame(x = c(2:5), y = c(11:14), z = c(3:6), g = c(4:7))
```

As usual, we can manually put them into a single list like this:

```
mylist <- list(A = df1, B = df2, C= df3)
```

**Problem:**

But right now, I have 1075 data frames having different dimensions, and I am stuck in putting them into a single list.

**What I have:**

Recently, I have a file (*ICON.RData*) can put the 1075 data frames into R environment directly. More specifically, this file includes those 1075 data frames + 1 data frame describing information of the 1075 dataframes, in which its first column (named *var_name*) comprising name of each of 1075 data frames. So, we easily have a name vector of all the data frame like this

*name <- ICON$var_name*

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: i am not sure, how your initial data is accessed. are you looking for this? `list<-lapply(your_data, read.csv)` ?

Comment: `mylist <- mget( ICON$var_name)` will put all the data frames into a list called `mylist`

Comment: Actually I don't have data as file.txt (or something like this) but only have a file as ICON.RData. So I can't use read.csv :( @D.J

Comment: Awsome @AllanCameron, This is what I am looking for. Please re-answer by clicking 'Answer Your Question', so I can mark your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
mylist <- mget( ICON$var_name)
```

will put all the data frames into a list called `mylist`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have `icon.RData` shown in the Note at the end we can load it into an environment `iconEnv` and then convert that environment to a list `iconList` or possibly just use `iconEnv` and don't bother converting it to a list in which case we can omit the last two lines of code.

```
load("icon.RData", envir = iconEnv <- new.env())

iconList <- as.list(iconEnv)
rm(iconEnv) # optional
```

### Note

Input file in reproducible form:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 11:15)  
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:9, y = 11:19, z = 8:16 )    
df3 <- data.frame(x = 2:5, y = 11:14, z = 3:6, g = 4:7)
save(df1, df2, df3, file = "icon.RData")
rm(df1, df2, df3)
```